# Feature extraction from text data set

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, text-processing, multilabel-classification

I have a query regarding the feature extraction of the text dataset. Using a preprocessed dataset from:

The preprocessed data is one line per document, with each line in the format:

```
feature:<count> .... feature:<count> #label#:<label>
```

Assume we have two lines:

```
<line 1> alpha: 3 beta:2 gamma: 1 delta: 0 echo:0 #label:1

<line 2> alpha: 0 foxtrot:0 mike: 0 beta: 1 delta:1 #label:0
```

So I want to extract the features such that I get:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAGjF.png)

So far I have written this code, but unable to proceed further:

```
import pandas as pd
dict={}
total=pd.DataFrame()
with open ('amazon_book.review', 'r') as data:
    for i in range(3):
        line=data.readline()
        for word in line.split():
            key,value=word.split(sep=":")
            dict[key]=value
```

Comment: first of all: `dict` is a default class, don't use it to name you variables. second: i am not able to understand what you are asking for. i have tried to run your code and it works fine except for the fact that there is a space after the `:` in features like `alpha`, `delta`, etc...

Comment: I want to get the unique words of the file as the columns and different lines as rows such that df[line 1][word]={word count in that line}. The main objective is to perform k-means clustering on this text dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Please use regex. Hope the below code helps. In the dataframe total you will get all your features and labels

```
import pandas as pd
import re

list_of_dict = []
str_feature_pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+\s*:\s+\d+)+')
str_label_pattern = re.compile(r'.*#(\w+:\d+)')

with open ('amazon_book.review', 'r') as data:
    for i in range(3):
        line=data.readline()
        feature_match = str_feature_pattern.findall(line)
        label_match = str_label_pattern.findall(line)
        dict = {}
        for f in feature_match:
          vals = f.split(sep=":")
          dict[vals[0]] = vals[1]
        label_val = label_match[0].split(sep=':')
        dict[label_val[0]] = label_val[1]
        list_of_dict.append(dict)
total=pd.DataFrame(list_of_dict)
```

Comment: @Surjya---------------------------------------------------------------------------
`IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-f5fbed225a0c> in <module>
     15           vals = f.split(sep=":")
     16           dict[vals[0]] = vals[1]
---> 17         label_val = label_match[0].split(sep=':')
     18         dict[label_val[0]] = label_val[1]
     19         list_of_dict.append(dict)

IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: In line 17 (label_val= = label_match[0].split(sep=':')), it says: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I have provided the code thinking that all your lines contains features and labels. It seems few of your lines does not contain the label. Debug your data if that is the case.